# Ubuntu consuming too much power after a certain error

Tags: boot, drivers, kernel

I got this error on booting:

> Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:

> -Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)

> -Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)

> -Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev) ALERT! UUID=3a07fc6c-73b9-4b46-8049-f0f8ea41820a does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

> BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.2) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

> (initramfs)_

Found solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/589899/missing-modules-cat-proc-modules-ls-dev-and-uuid-doesnt-exist-in-busybox), and accordingly went to SATA in BIOS, but AHCI was already enabled.

I tried rebooting, and it loaded without any errors. But since then ubuntu has been consuming much more power than it usually does.

Anyone explain what was the issue and how can I fix excessive power consumption?

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  No *supported* release of Ubuntu uses the version of `busybox`

Comment: @guiverc it's 22.04 LTS :0 is it something to worry about if my version seems to support?

Comment: If it was Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, your `busybox` version would be `1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3` yet you show a message from something packaged before 18.04.  Your version shows details are incorrect or significant details are possibly missing.  Also if you refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site.